# is it possible to fetch a single column result as string instead of array in python?

Tags: python, mysql, arrays

I wonder if its possible to fetch data from database as string instead of a result set array

the thing is that I need to have an array of strings that I'm fetching from a database table

```
Table `example`
+-------------+
| id, name    |
| 1,  string1 |
| 2,  string2 |
| 3,  string3 |
+-------------+
```

now if I'm fetching from it with using the cursor

```
cursor.execute("SELECT DISTINCT `name` FROM `example`")
rs = cursor.fetchall()
```

the result I'm getting is:

```
rs = [['string1'], ['string2'], ['string3']]
```

and what I'm trying to achieve is:

```
rs = ['string1', 'string2', 'string3']
```

right now to achieve it I iterating through all the fetched result and casting it to a new array like that:

```
newArr = []
for row in rs:
   newArr.append(row[0])
```

Is there any quicker way to get this result?

The reason I want to do it is because I want to check if a string exists is inside the array

```
if "string4" in newArr:
  doSomething()
```

I'm trying to do it in this way because I don't want to send for each string I'm checking a query to the database and do something like

```
for somestring in stringArray:
  cursor.execute("SELECT `name` FROM `example` WHERE `name` = %s", (somestring,))
  rs = cursor.fetchall()
  if len(rs) > 0:
    doSomething()
```

because I'll I have around 20k strings to check so I think its quicker to first fetch all the strings as array from the database and then check if its exists in the array.

so what you think is the quickest way to achieve my goal?
and is it possible to fetch directly from the database a result as a string instead of an array?

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The itertools library has a [chain](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain) function which can unlist the iterables that is passed in

```
from itertools import chain

rs = [['string1'], ['string2'], ['string3']]

list(chain(*rs))
```

would yield result as below

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer!. I wonder if using the chain function from the itertools library is faster than the "newArr" thingy I've just did to get same result. what do you think?

Comment: @TylerPerry I don't think it will be, but there's an easy way to check: [`timeit.timeit`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/timeit.html)

Comment: I'm checking. If it will be I'll accept your answer :)!